# Bug in display of recently earned badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

When I go to my profile, on the Activity tab under Badges, I see this:

[image: topbadges]

Notice how the badge only has the open bracket `{`. Now when I scroll down to the badge section near the bottom, I see this:

[image: bottombadges]

Here the brackets are matched `{}`, as I assume they should be. Has anyone else noticed this? For reference, I'm on Safari 9.0.3.

Comment: Looks ok on Chrome here

Comment: Looks OK on Firefox as well. Could be Safari-specific or resolution-specific.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275894/badge-card-icons-cut-off

Comment: @m0sa Awesome sauce. Thanks!